# Error while making outbound call on twilio

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-php, twilio-click-to-call

I am new to twilio.I am using twilio trial account and I am using php.I have created my account and the verification code was sent to my number .But when i try to make a call i get the error

> Error: The source phone number provided, +1937xxxxxx6, is not yet verified for your account. You may only make calls from phone numbers that you've verified or purchased from Twilio.

Here is my code

```
<?php
// Include the Twilio PHP library
require 'twilio-php-master/Services/Twilio.php';

// Twilio REST API version
$version = "2010-04-01";

// Set our Account SID and AuthToken
$sid = 'Axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxffa58';
$token = 'f878xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxeb05';

// A phone number you have previously validated with Twilio
$phonenumber = '+19xxxxxxxx6';

// Instantiate a new Twilio Rest Client
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token, $version);

try {
    // Initiate a new outbound call
    $call = $client->account->calls->create(
        $phonenumber, // The number of the phone initiating the call
        '+91xxxxxxxx7', // The number of the phone receiving call
        'http://demo.twilio.com/welcome/voice' // The URL Twilio will request when the call is answered
    );
    echo 'Started call: ' . $call->sid;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: Is +19xxxxxxxx6 the number that received the verification code?

Comment: Can you check that you've verified the number here: https://www.twilio.com/user/account/phone-numbers/verified

Comment: ecorvo ,..no the number that received the verification code is my personal number.I tried giving it as the source number .Then also it dint work.Gives the same error

Comment: +Megan Speir.. Yes my personal number is there in the list

Answer (score -1):

It happened to me when using the test account/token.
I double checked that the my phone number is verified but it was giving me this error.
Then I replaced the test account with my real account sid/token and the call succeeds.

I consider this as a bug in their system.

tested with python 3.6, twilio 6.16.2